# Apache2 Request on SSL waits until time-out expired to return data

Tags: apache, ssl, ubuntu-12.04, tls1.2, gnutls

I am working with a server that I recently inherited from a departed developer.  The server returns XML documents via a REST-ful interface over an SSL port.  For small documents, the data is returned quickly.  For larger (say, larger than 1 MB), the server waits until the server time-out value is exhausted and then returns the data.

I know this because if I set the time-out value to five minutes the data will be returned to a browser in a little over 300 seconds.  If I drop the time-out value to two minutes, it will be returned in about 120 seconds.  If I drop it to 10 seconds, then the data is returned in about 10 seconds.

Now, if I set my VirtualHost to port 80, the data is returned almost instantly, which is what I expect.

There are a number of diagnostics in the apache log files such as:

```
[Thu Apr 28 16:46:44.234689 2016] [ssl:info] [pid 22606] (70014)End of file found: [client 172.26.61.243:62030] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
[Thu Apr 28 16:46:44.237818 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 22509] ssl_engine_io.c(1212): (70014)End of file found: [client 172.26.61.243:62030] AH02007: SSL handshake interrupted by system [Hint: Stop button pressed in browser?!]
[Thu Apr 28 16:46:44.569913 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 22426] ssl_engine_io.c(1212): (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 172.26.61.243:62031] AH02007: SSL handshake interrupted by system [Hint: Stop button pressed in browser?!]
```

I do not know if these are relevant nor where to look for a solution.  I have searched the internet, Apache and SSL documentation and found nothing relevant or useful.

Comment: Any updates on that one :) ?